# How to disable special newline and other characters in js strings

Tags: javascript, string

I am creating a simple string but all my letters after backslashes are being interpretted as special tags. Example:

```
const string = "C:\Users"
console.log(string)
```

The `\U` doesnt get printed in the final string so the console output looks like this: `C:sers`. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow ! Can you confirm there are no quotes (simple quotes or double quotes) around your string ?

Comment: There are qoutes I just didnt add them into the post will edit them in.

Comment: Great ! thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape these characters by adding an extra `\`

```js
const path =  "C:\\users";

console.log(path)
```